# Why doesn't an object with less density than a fluid float 100% above the fluid level?

Tags: forces, pressure, free-body-diagram, fluid-statics, density

If an object is less dense than that of a fluid, then why doesn't it float completely over the fluid level? Why does some part of the object remain submerged in it? Can there be an object that can float 100% on water? (If this involves surface tension (Is that what it's called?), please clear that up, too. Don't understand that concept yet. But it would be better if your answer didn't include that.)

Comment: What would be the force keeping it up?

Comment: Do you understand why and how objects float to begin with? Because the answer to how an object floats answers your question and more right there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The buoyant force on an object is equal to the weight of the fluid that the object displaces.  If you hold an object just at a fluid surface, there is gravity acting on it, which is opposed by the force that you have to apply to the object to hold it stationary, but there is no buoyant force on it because it hasn't displaced any fluid.  As you lower the object into a fluid, the force of gravity pulling it down is constant but the buoyant force on the object increases as it displaces more fluid.  At some point, a floating object will displace enough fluid for the buoyant force pushing the object up to equal the force of gravity pulling it down, and the object will float with some portion of the object above the fluid.

Regarding this phenomenon, density is a bit of a "red herring".  While it is true that objects that are less dense than a given fluid will float in the fluid, it is also true that objects that are more dense than a fluid can float in the fluid.  For a cargo ship at sea, the hull of the ship is made of steel, which is approximately 7 times as dense as sea water, yet the ship still floats because the ship's hull has a shape that allows it to displace its weight of water before it sinks in that water.

Comment: You raise a fair point, but assigning a single unambiguous density to an object only makes sense if (a) the object is homogeneous or (b) the density is understood to be an average taken over some region; in either case, the subsequent density *is* the quantity which determines whether the object will sink or float.

Answer (score 1):

Because it has more density than the air. Unless it doesn't, in which case it will happily float miles above the fluid

Comment: The same effect of partial submersion occurs in a vacuum, so the presence of air is immaterial there. But your answer is relevant for the possibility of zero submersion. Please consider expanding it with more detail.

Comment: It has more density than a vacuum. Unless it doesn't, in which case it will happily float lightyears through the vacuum

Answer (score 1):

> If an object is less dense than that of a fluid, then why doesn't it
> float completely over the fluid level?

Not exactly sure what you mean by "completely", but the fraction of the volume of a floating object that is below the fluid level (submerged) will equal the ratio of the average density of the object to the density of the fluid. The fraction above the fluid level is therefore one minus that fraction.

I suppose a air inflated balloon would come closest to completely sitting atop the fluid level as its density would be very low compared to the fluid, the exact amount depending on the fluid.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why would it sit on the water surface rather than rising in the air?

Comment: @nasu You're right I meant an air filled balloon. Will correct. But even with helium if the density of the combination of the balloon material plus helium were greater than air, though not likely, it could

Comment: If the overall density is larger than that of air it will displace water.  For both air or helium balloons. And if the density is equal or less than that of air the water becomes irrelevant.

Comment: @nasu I believe that's what I said when I referred to the "average density" of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually there doesn't exist such a body which can stay with its volume completely, unsubmerged. Whenever, a body is placed over fluid, it displaces some water, (whose value is equal to fraction of volume submerged inside fluid). When the fluid is displaced, buoyant force acts on body.

Let's take body of mass $m$ volume, $V$, fluid of density $\rho$. Let fraction of volume submerged be $x$.

For an equilibrium:

$$mg=m_{\text{water displaced}}g$$
$$mg=\rho (xV)g$$
$$x=\frac{m}{V\rho}$$

If, our body is completely unsubmerged, like you mentioned, then $x=0$, and it will yield some absurd results in our equation.

Surface tension (of water), usually comes to play for small objects (with respect to us) like particulalry insects which have to fight surface tension to avoid drowning.
Small objects when gently placed often stay float with help of surface tension, but they also have some part submerged and experience buoyant force.

Comment: *“Well, actually there doesn't exist such a body which can stay with its volume completely, unsubmerged.”* What about a blimp or a balloon, as suggested by the other answer? It would be useful to discuss what’s happening there.

Comment: As, I said, minute fraction of volume, will be submerged. If its 100% above water, then technically it isn't *floating* on water. Moreover, blimp or balloon has extra buoyant force  of air trapped inside.

Comment: The balloon is an irrelevant side track.  Either it floats in the air and then the existence of water does nothing to the behaviour or it doesn't and then it displaces some water.